# Repeatedly Subtracting Numbers in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to take the number 1663126215 and I want to subtract "8400" from this number 1000 times and keep all the results. I thought that maybe I can write a loop for this:

```
the_list = list()

for (i in 1:1000)

{

new_i = 1663126215 - 8400*i

the_list[[i]] <- new_i

}
```

I am not sure I have this done correctly - can someone please confirm? Are there other ways I could have done this?

Thank you!

Comment: Just `1663126215 - 8400 * 1:1000`, no need of a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using a sequence here:

```r
output <- 1663126215 - 8400*seq(1:1000)
output

[1] 1663117815 1663109415 1663101015 1663092615 1663084215 1663075815
[7] 1663067415 1663059015 1663050615 1663042215 ...
```

Comment: What exactly is `seq(1:1000)`?